# Which version of firefox will support Recall Monkey?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, add-on

Mozilla Labs has an extention called "Recall monkey", it stop working with new versions of Firefox, my question is what is the last Firefox version that does support it. i searched it but found nothing , Any help is appreciated.

these links may help:

Mozilla labs:
http://mozillalabs.com/prospector/2011/06/20/recallmonkey-finds-what-you-forget/

Addons link:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-recall-monkey/

what does this addon do:
https://superuser.com/questions/296501/is-there-a-way-to-search-the-text-of-my-browsing-history-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [plugin website](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-recall-monkey/) it should be supported from version 12 up to 21.*

Comment: website says : Works with Firefox 12.0 and later. it didn't write version 21.* . where did you found that?

Comment: Under "Download anyway" it says "**Works with Firefox 12.0 - 21.***"

Comment: thanks. if you open that page with firefox it just says : "Add To Firefox" instead of "download anyway"

Answer (score 1):

Searching browsing history is super cool. I think they are bring it back with this Test Pilot addon - Activity Stream - https://testpilot.firefox.com/experiments/activity-stream

Comment: this addon doesn't do exactly what Recall Monkey do , but it is handy , thanks to inform